# Использование значений текущей строки (по алиасу) внутри аналитической функции Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть некая табличка:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
  COL1 INTEGER,
  COL2 INTEGER
);
```

И есть некий **неработающий** запрос с аналитической функцией:

```
SELECT
    TEST_TABLE.Col1,
    TEST_TABLE.Col2 AS SUPER_Col2,
    SUM(Col1 - SUPER_Col2) OVER ()
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что значение `SUPER_Col2` из текущей строки не доступно внутри `SUM()`.

Безусловно существует куча вариантов как сделать это задание, но просто хотелось бы узнать, можно ли без танцев с бубнами использовать значение текущей строки внутри аналитической функции, как в указанном запросе?

Пример таблицы:

```
Col1    Col2
4       1
5       2
6       3
```

Результат запроса:

```
Col1    SUPER_Col2    Sum
1       1             ((4 - 1) + (5 - 1) + (6 - 1))= 12
2       2             ((4 - 2) + (5 - 2) + (6 - 2))= 9
3       3             ((4 - 3) + (5 - 3) + (6 - 3))= 6
```

То есть SUM для каждого значения Col1 вычитает текущее значение Col2

Comment: а зачем Вы обращаетесь к алиасу? Можно так: 

SELECT
    tt.Col2 AS SUPER_Col2,
    SUM(tt.Col1 - tt.Col2) OVER ()
FROM TEST_TABLE tt;

Comment: В конце вопроса добавил пример

Comment: Не понятно, зачем ссылаться на колонку. то что вы хотите на выходе вообще то сводиться к `sum(col1) over() - (count(*) over()) * col2`

Comment: Mike, ваш вариант нельзя будет применить для операций сравнения.

Вроде такого:

`SELECT`

    `TEST_TABLE.Col1,`
    `TEST_TABLE.Col2 AS SUPER_Col2,`

    `SUM((CAST((Col1 > SUPER_Col2) AS INT)) OVER ()`

`FROM TEST_TABLE;`

Comment: Безусловно существует куча вариантов как сделать это задание, но просто хотелось бы узнать, можно ли без танцев с бубнами использовать значение текущей строки внутри аналитической функции, как в указанном запросе?

Comment: @МихаилЯ, попробуйте использовать CTE

Comment: @МихаилЯ Тогда напишите конечную цель. Что бы найти решение для начала надо иметь нормальное описание задачи. А сравнивать в фразе select обычно не требуется, надо выдать все необходимые значения, обернуть еще одним запросом и там в where уже сравнивать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Проблема заключается в том, что значение SUPER_Col2 из текущей строки не доступно внутри  SUM()

`SUPER_Col2` это алиас и он не доступен в листе текущего выражения `SELECT`. Так нельзя делать:

```
select 1 a, 2 b, sum (a+b) over () sum from dual;
```

> ORA-00904: "B": invalid identifier

Используйте имя колонки. И судя по желаемому результату, её не нужно использовать в аналитической функции:

```
create table t1 as select rownum+3 col1, rownum col2 from xmlTable ('1 to 3');

select 
    col1, col2, sum(col1) over () - (col2 * count(1) over ()) sum
from t1;

      COL1       COL2        SUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1         12
         5          2          9
         6          3          6
```

---

Вне рамок ответа, так как из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899125/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-oracle-sql#comment1473068_899125)).

> ... нельзя будет применить для операций сравнения. Вроде такого:
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>     TEST_TABLE.Col1, TEST_TABLE.Col2 AS SUPER_Col2, 
>     SUM((CAST((Col1 > SUPER_Col2) AS INT)) OVER () 
> FROM TEST_TABLE;
> ```

Логические выражения с использованием операторов сравнения могут быть использованы напрямую в выражениях, таких как:  `WHERE`, `HAVING`, `ON`, а так же в операторе `CASE`. В SQL нет типа `BOOLEAN` и результат логических выражений не может быть преобразован оператором `CAST` в какой-то другой тип данных.
Посчитать, сколько строк, где значение первой колонки больше второй, можно так:

```
select 
    col1, col2, sum (case when col1 > col2 then 1 else 0 end) over () res
FROM t1;

      COL1       COL2        RES
---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1          3
         5          2          3
         6          3          3
```